# MAX1555 Alternatives

Tags: lithium, charge

As you know, the [MAX1555](http://datasheets.maxim-ic.com/en/ds/MAX1551-MAX1555.pdf) is a popular single cell lithium polymer charger. It can take USB power directly, restricting the charge current to 100mA or so.

Are there any other MAX1555 alternatives that are your favourites? I'm just browsing around for alternatives at the moment, seeing if they offer some other features.

Comment: I am interested in knowing if there are chips that will detect if its plugged into a usb charger and increase the charge current limit.

Comment: I added a link to the MAX1555's datasheet. We're trying to make users aware of the importance of this, especially for less common parts, so that others don't have to go searching for it and that everybody is sure to be talking about the same thing. Just trying to cultivate good habits.

Answer (score 2):

I know adafruit.com sells two LiPoly charger boards, one uses the [MCP73833](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en027785) the other uses [MCP73861](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en020210).